# Escape from Monkey Island - "ScummVM could not find any game in the specified directory!"

Tags: scummvm, monkey-island-series

I tried to get Monkey Island 4 running using [ScummVM](https://github.com/scummvm/scummvm#310-escape-from-monkey-island-notes), but it always claims that there is no game:

- Android 2.2.1pre "ScummVM could not find any game in the specified
  directory!"
- Linux Snap 2.2.0 "ScummVM konnte im gewählten
  Verzeichnis kein Spiel finden!"

[image]

I probably misunderstood the documentation which files should be copied. If there is anybody out there who got this working, could you please share your file tree with me?

```
├── artAll.m4b
├── artJam.m4b
├── artLuc.m4b
├── artMel.m4b
├── artMon.m4b
├── i9n.m4b
├── lip.m4b
├── local.m4b
├── MonkeyUpdate_DEU.exe
├── Movies
│   ├── bank.m4b
│   ├── dock.m4b
│   ├── dumm.m4b
│   ├── ela2.m4b
│   ├── ela3.m4b
│   ├── espy.m4b
│   ├── finis.m4b
│   ├── gmrr.m4b
│   ├── herm.m4b
│   ├── home1.m4b
│   ├── home2.m4b
│   ├── intro_a.m4b
│   ├── intro_b.m4b
│   ├── melt.m4b
│   ├── moh_close_hat.m4b
│   ├── moh_close_nohat.m4b
│   ├── moh_open_hat.m4b
│   ├── moh_open_nohat.m4b
│   ├── nose.m4b
│   ├── oznx.m4b
│   ├── rock1B.m4b
│   ├── rock1C.m4b
│   ├── rock.m4b
│   └── sory.m4b
├── sfx.m4b
├── Textures
│   ├── FullMonkeyMap1.imt
│   ├── FullMonkeyMap2.imt
│   ├── mego
│   │   ├── A
│   │   │   ├── 1000.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1000.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1115.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1115.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1117.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1117.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1118.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1118.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1119.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1119.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1120.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1120.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1125.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1125.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1130.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1130.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1135.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1135.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1140.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1140.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1145.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1145.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1146.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1146.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1147.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1147.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1150.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1150.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1155.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1155.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1160.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1160.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1165.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1165.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1166.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1166.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1170.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1170.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1171.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1171.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1172.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1172.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1173.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1173.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1175.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1175.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1180.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1180.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1185.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1185.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1205.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1205.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 1210.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 1210.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 7200.jmm
│   │   │   └── 7200.m4b
│   │   ├── B
│   │   │   ├── 2100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2106.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2106.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2107.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2107.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2108.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2108.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2115.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2115.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2116.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2116.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2117.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2117.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2118.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2118.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2119.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2119.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2120.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2120.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2125.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2125.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2127.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2127.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2130.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2130.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2135.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2135.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2140.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2140.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2145.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2145.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2150.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2150.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2155.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2155.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2160.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2160.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2165.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2165.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2170.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2170.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2175.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2175.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2185.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2185.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2186.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2186.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2190.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2190.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2195.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2195.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2200.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2200.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2207.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2207.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2208.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2208.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2210.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 2210.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2215.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 2220.m4b
│   │   │   └── 2225.m4b
│   │   ├── C
│   │   │   ├── 3100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3102.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3102.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3106.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3106.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3107.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3107.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3110.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3110.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3115.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3115.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3120.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3120.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3125.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3125.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3130.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3130.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3135.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3135.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3140.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3140.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3145.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3145.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3147.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3147.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3150.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3150.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3200.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3200.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3205.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3205.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 3210.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 3210.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4106.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4106.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4110.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4110.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4115.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4115.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4120.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 4120.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 4215.jmm
│   │   │   └── 4215.m4b
│   │   ├── D
│   │   │   ├── 5100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5106.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5106.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5110.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5110.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5115.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5115.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5117.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5117.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5120.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5120.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5125.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5125.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5130.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5130.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5135.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5135.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5136.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5136.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5137.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5137.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5138.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5138.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5140.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5140.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5141.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5141.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5142.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5142.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5145.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5145.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5150.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5150.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5155.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5155.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5160.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5160.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5165.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5165.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5170.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5170.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5200.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5200.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5205.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5205.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5215.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5215.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5220.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5220.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5225.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5225.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 5230.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 5230.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 6100.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 6100.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 6105.jmm
│   │   │   ├── 6105.m4b
│   │   │   ├── 6110.jmm
│   │   │   └── 6110.m4b
│   │   └── S
│   │       ├── 1110.jmm
│   │       ├── 1110.m4b
│   │       ├── 1195.jmm
│   │       ├── 1195.m4b
│   │       ├── 1200.jmm
│   │       ├── 1200.m4b
│   │       ├── 1215.jmm
│   │       ├── 1215.m4b
│   │       └── 7210.m4b
│   └── spago
│       ├── A
│       │   ├── 1000.jmm
│       │   ├── 1000.m4b
│       │   ├── 1100.jmm
│       │   ├── 1100.m4b
│       │   ├── 1105.jmm
│       │   ├── 1105.m4b
│       │   ├── 1115.jmm
│       │   ├── 1115.m4b
│       │   ├── 1117.jmm
│       │   ├── 1117.m4b
│       │   ├── 1118.jmm
│       │   ├── 1118.m4b
│       │   ├── 1119.jmm
│       │   ├── 1119.m4b
│       │   ├── 1120.jmm
│       │   ├── 1120.m4b
│       │   ├── 1125.jmm
│       │   ├── 1125.m4b
│       │   ├── 1130.jmm
│       │   ├── 1130.m4b
│       │   ├── 1135.jmm
│       │   ├── 1135.m4b
│       │   ├── 1140.jmm
│       │   ├── 1140.m4b
│       │   ├── 1145.jmm
│       │   ├── 1145.m4b
│       │   ├── 1146.jmm
│       │   ├── 1146.m4b
│       │   ├── 1147.jmm
│       │   ├── 1147.m4b
│       │   ├── 1150.jmm
│       │   ├── 1150.m4b
│       │   ├── 1155.jmm
│       │   ├── 1155.m4b
│       │   ├── 1160.jmm
│       │   ├── 1160.m4b
│       │   ├── 1165.jmm
│       │   ├── 1165.m4b
│       │   ├── 1166.jmm
│       │   ├── 1166.m4b
│       │   ├── 1170.jmm
│       │   ├── 1170.m4b
│       │   ├── 1171.jmm
│       │   ├── 1171.m4b
│       │   ├── 1172.jmm
│       │   ├── 1172.m4b
│       │   ├── 1173.jmm
│       │   ├── 1173.m4b
│       │   ├── 1175.jmm
│       │   ├── 1175.m4b
│       │   ├── 1180.jmm
│       │   ├── 1180.m4b
│       │   ├── 1185.jmm
│       │   ├── 1185.m4b
│       │   ├── 1205.jmm
│       │   ├── 1205.m4b
│       │   ├── 1210.jmm
│       │   ├── 1210.m4b
│       │   ├── 7200.jmm
│       │   └── 7200.m4b
│       ├── B
│       │   ├── 2100.jmm
│       │   ├── 2100.m4b
│       │   ├── 2105.jmm
│       │   ├── 2105.m4b
│       │   ├── 2106.jmm
│       │   ├── 2106.m4b
│       │   ├── 2107.jmm
│       │   ├── 2107.m4b
│       │   ├── 2108.jmm
│       │   ├── 2108.m4b
│       │   ├── 2115.jmm
│       │   ├── 2115.m4b
│       │   ├── 2116.jmm
│       │   ├── 2116.m4b
│       │   ├── 2117.jmm
│       │   ├── 2117.m4b
│       │   ├── 2118.jmm
│       │   ├── 2118.m4b
│       │   ├── 2119.jmm
│       │   ├── 2119.m4b
│       │   ├── 2120.jmm
│       │   ├── 2120.m4b
│       │   ├── 2125.jmm
│       │   ├── 2125.m4b
│       │   ├── 2127.jmm
│       │   ├── 2127.m4b
│       │   ├── 2130.jmm
│       │   ├── 2130.m4b
│       │   ├── 2135.jmm
│       │   ├── 2135.m4b
│       │   ├── 2140.jmm
│       │   ├── 2140.m4b
│       │   ├── 2145.jmm
│       │   ├── 2145.m4b
│       │   ├── 2150.jmm
│       │   ├── 2150.m4b
│       │   ├── 2155.jmm
│       │   ├── 2155.m4b
│       │   ├── 2160.jmm
│       │   ├── 2160.m4b
│       │   ├── 2165.jmm
│       │   ├── 2165.m4b
│       │   ├── 2170.jmm
│       │   ├── 2170.m4b
│       │   ├── 2175.jmm
│       │   ├── 2175.m4b
│       │   ├── 2185.jmm
│       │   ├── 2185.m4b
│       │   ├── 2186.jmm
│       │   ├── 2186.m4b
│       │   ├── 2190.jmm
│       │   ├── 2190.m4b
│       │   ├── 2195.jmm
│       │   ├── 2195.m4b
│       │   ├── 2200.jmm
│       │   ├── 2200.m4b
│       │   ├── 2207.jmm
│       │   ├── 2207.m4b
│       │   ├── 2208.jmm
│       │   ├── 2208.m4b
│       │   ├── 2210.jmm
│       │   ├── 2210.m4b
│       │   ├── 2215.m4b
│       │   ├── 2220.m4b
│       │   └── 2225.m4b
│       ├── C
│       │   ├── 3100.jmm
│       │   ├── 3100.m4b
│       │   ├── 3102.jmm
│       │   ├── 3102.m4b
│       │   ├── 3105.jmm
│       │   ├── 3105.m4b
│       │   ├── 3106.jmm
│       │   ├── 3106.m4b
│       │   ├── 3107.jmm
│       │   ├── 3107.m4b
│       │   ├── 3110.jmm
│       │   ├── 3110.m4b
│       │   ├── 3115.jmm
│       │   ├── 3115.m4b
│       │   ├── 3120.jmm
│       │   ├── 3120.m4b
│       │   ├── 3125.jmm
│       │   ├── 3125.m4b
│       │   ├── 3130.jmm
│       │   ├── 3130.m4b
│       │   ├── 3135.jmm
│       │   ├── 3135.m4b
│       │   ├── 3140.jmm
│       │   ├── 3140.m4b
│       │   ├── 3145.jmm
│       │   ├── 3145.m4b
│       │   ├── 3147.jmm
│       │   ├── 3147.m4b
│       │   ├── 3150.jmm
│       │   ├── 3150.m4b
│       │   ├── 3200.jmm
│       │   ├── 3200.m4b
│       │   ├── 3205.jmm
│       │   ├── 3205.m4b
│       │   ├── 3210.jmm
│       │   ├── 3210.m4b
│       │   ├── 4100.jmm
│       │   ├── 4100.m4b
│       │   ├── 4105.jmm
│       │   ├── 4105.m4b
│       │   ├── 4106.jmm
│       │   ├── 4106.m4b
│       │   ├── 4110.jmm
│       │   ├── 4110.m4b
│       │   ├── 4115.jmm
│       │   ├── 4115.m4b
│       │   ├── 4120.jmm
│       │   ├── 4120.m4b
│       │   ├── 4215.jmm
│       │   └── 4215.m4b
│       ├── D
│       │   ├── 5100.jmm
│       │   ├── 5100.m4b
│       │   ├── 5105.jmm
│       │   ├── 5105.m4b
│       │   ├── 5106.jmm
│       │   ├── 5106.m4b
│       │   ├── 5110.jmm
│       │   ├── 5110.m4b
│       │   ├── 5115.jmm
│       │   ├── 5115.m4b
│       │   ├── 5117.jmm
│       │   ├── 5117.m4b
│       │   ├── 5120.jmm
│       │   ├── 5120.m4b
│       │   ├── 5125.jmm
│       │   ├── 5125.m4b
│       │   ├── 5130.jmm
│       │   ├── 5130.m4b
│       │   ├── 5135.jmm
│       │   ├── 5135.m4b
│       │   ├── 5136.jmm
│       │   ├── 5136.m4b
│       │   ├── 5137.jmm
│       │   ├── 5137.m4b
│       │   ├── 5138.jmm
│       │   ├── 5138.m4b
│       │   ├── 5140.jmm
│       │   ├── 5140.m4b
│       │   ├── 5141.jmm
│       │   ├── 5141.m4b
│       │   ├── 5142.jmm
│       │   ├── 5142.m4b
│       │   ├── 5145.jmm
│       │   ├── 5145.m4b
│       │   ├── 5150.jmm
│       │   ├── 5150.m4b
│       │   ├── 5155.jmm
│       │   ├── 5155.m4b
│       │   ├── 5160.jmm
│       │   ├── 5160.m4b
│       │   ├── 5165.jmm
│       │   ├── 5165.m4b
│       │   ├── 5170.jmm
│       │   ├── 5170.m4b
│       │   ├── 5200.jmm
│       │   ├── 5200.m4b
│       │   ├── 5205.jmm
│       │   ├── 5205.m4b
│       │   ├── 5215.jmm
│       │   ├── 5215.m4b
│       │   ├── 5220.jmm
│       │   ├── 5220.m4b
│       │   ├── 5225.jmm
│       │   ├── 5225.m4b
│       │   ├── 5230.jmm
│       │   ├── 5230.m4b
│       │   ├── 6100.jmm
│       │   ├── 6100.m4b
│       │   ├── 6105.jmm
│       │   ├── 6105.m4b
│       │   ├── 6110.jmm
│       │   └── 6110.m4b
│       └── S
│           ├── 1110.jmm
│           ├── 1110.m4b
│           ├── 1195.jmm
│           ├── 1195.m4b
│           ├── 1200.jmm
│           ├── 1200.m4b
│           ├── 1215.jmm
│           ├── 1215.m4b
│           └── 7210.m4b
├── voiceAll.m4b
├── voiceJam.m4b
├── voiceLuc.m4b
├── voiceMel.m4b
└── voiceMon.m4b

14 directories, 533 files
```

Comment: TL;DR: the current release version of ScummVM does not work with MI4 - gotta use the most recent stable nightly builds - there is a wiki page for the file tree: https://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php?title=Escape_from_Monkey_Island#Required_data_files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of late 2020, the ResidualVM project is being merged with ScummVM.

*(side note: I was never been able to get "Escape from Monkey Island" working with the old Residual... game runs natively in Windows XP/7 without being installed, although you must have the discs or disc images mounted as a CD in order to play)*

Version v2.2.0-v2.3.0pre of ScummVM gives exactly the error message you have.

[image]

Use the most recent daily build (Version 2.6.0) from [ScummVm.org](https://www.scummvm.org/downloads/#daily)

[Here](https://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php?title=Escape_from_Monkey_Island#Required_data_files) is a full list of the required data files, with instructions.
This game is a 2-disc set, and it is not as easy as just combining the directories together.

Here is what you need to do:

- Copy all the files from CD1 "MonkeyData" into their own directory
- Copy "MonkeyInstall\local.m4b" to "MonkeyData\local.m4b"
- Copy "MonkeyInstall\patch.m4b" to "MonkeyData\patch.m4b"

  - This file seems to be missing on some CDs (e.g. 2.0 from 24.01.2007)
- Rename "MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt" to "FullMonkeyMap1.imt" *(from CD1)*
- Combine all the files/subdirectories from CD2 "MonkeyData\Movies"

  - *(there should be no conflicts)*
- Combine all the files/subdirectories from CD2 "MonkeyData\Textures"

  - *(any conflicts are identical files)*
- Rename "MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt" to "FullMonkeyMap2.imt" *(from CD2)*
- Combine all the files (not subdirectories) from CD2 "MonkeyData"

  - do not overwrite "voiceAll.m4b" *(make sure to use the copy from CD1)*
- Put the language specific version of [update](https://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php?title=Escape_from_Monkey_Island#Required_data_files) in "MonkeyData"

```
mkdir .\MonkeyData -Force | Out-Null
# Copy all the files from CD1 "MonkeyData" into their own directory
Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD1\Monkey4\MonkeyData\* .\MonkeyData -Recurse
# Copy "MonkeyInstall\local.m4b" to "MonkeyData\local.m4b"
Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD1\Monkey4\MonkeyInstall\local.m4b ./MonkeyData\local.m4b

# Copy "MonkeyInstall\patch.m4b" to "MonkeyData\patch.m4b"
if (Test-Path -Path .\Monkey4_CD1\Monkey4\MonkeyInstall\patch.m4b -PathType Leaf) {
    Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD1\Monkey4\MonkeyInstall\patch.m4b ./MonkeyData\patch.m4b
}
# Rename "MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt" to "FullMonkeyMap1.imt" (from CD1)
Move-Item  ./MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt ./MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap1.imt
# Combine all the files/subdirectories from CD2 "MonkeyData\Movies"
#     (there should be no conflicts)
Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD2\Monkey4\MonkeyData\Movies\* ./MonkeyData\Movies\ -Recurse -Force
# Combine all the files/subdirectories from CD2 "MonkeyData\Textures"
#     (any conflicts are identical files)
Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD2\Monkey4\MonkeyData\Textures\* ./MonkeyData\Textures\ -Recurse -Force
# Rename "MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt" to "FullMonkeyMap2.imt" (from CD2)
Move-Item  ./MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap.imt ./MonkeyData\Textures\FullMonkeyMap2.imt
# Combine all the files (not subdirectories) from CD2 "MonkeyData"
#     do not overwrite "voiceAll.m4b" (make sure to use the copy from CD1)
Copy-Item .\Monkey4_CD2\Monkey4\MonkeyData\* ./MonkeyData\ -Exclude @('Textures', 'voiceAll.m4b', 'Movies')

# MonkeyUpdate_DEU.exe got from a source from https://wiki.scummvm.org/index.php?title=Escape_from_Monkey_Island#Required_data_files
Copy-Item ./MonkeyUpdate_DEU.exe ./MonkeyData\
```

---

Now you can add the game to ScummVM nightly:

- Select "Add Game..." from the menu on the right
- Navigate to "MonkeyData" *(or wherever "local.m4b" and the other M4B files are located)*
- Highlight that directory, and click "Choose" in the file browser
- Click "OK" back in ScummVM

You will receive a warning, but the game will start with music!

[image]